# Map comparing over heterogeneous criteria

Tags: sorting, haskell, types

```
mconcat (map comparing [length, last, id]) "abc" "def"
```

This of course doesn't typecheck. The list contains functions from the same domain to different codomains. But I hope the intent is clear. Can some type annotation or another workaround (not putting comparing in 3 places or something alike) make it work?

Comment: Any reason why you want to do it like this ? This is not the recommended way to write haskell code.

Comment: I've seen it in examples (some of them linked below) showcasing the Ordering monoid. It makes me wonder if the repetition of comparing can be abstracted. I've come across similar cases in mine and others' programmes, not related to sorting.

Additional question, prompted by your second sentence: what would be the recommended way in such cases?

http://www.mjoldfield.com/atelier/2015/04/monoid.html
https://byorgey.wordpress.com/2011/04/18/monoids-for-maybe/
http://martijn.van.steenbergen.nl/journal/2008/12/21/comparing-multiple-criteria/

Answer (score 7):

It goes quite smoothly as long as you don't mind not putting the functions in a list:

```
GHCi> :t comparing length <> comparing last <> comparing id
comparing length <> comparing last <> comparing id
  :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> Ordering
GHCi> (comparing length <> comparing last <> comparing id) "abcd" "abc"
GT
GHCi> (comparing length <> comparing last <> comparing id) "abd" "abc"
GT
GHCi> (comparing length <> comparing last <> comparing id) "aac" "abc"
LT
```

This exploits both the monoid instance for functions (a monoid on the results) and the one for `Ordering` (which does [the intuitvely obvious thing](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-302)).

Given that the result type of the projection function you give to `comparing` doesn't actually appear in the final result, if you really want a list you can appeal to an existential type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

import Data.Ord

data Measurement a where
    Measurement :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> Measurement a

comparingHet :: Measurement a -> a -> a -> Ordering
comparingHet (Measurement f) = comparing f
```

```
GHCi> criteria = [Measurement length, Measurement last, Measurement id]
GHCi> mconcat (comparingHet <$> criteria) "aac" "abc"
LT
GHCi> foldMap comparingHet criteria "aac" "abc"  -- Alternative spelling.
LT
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Comparison` from `Data.Functor.Contravariant`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html#t:Comparison), which is only a little bit less tidy:

```
GHCi> import Data.Functor.Contravariant
GHCi> criteria = Comparison <$> [comparing length, comparing last, comparing id]
GHCi> getComparison (mconcat criteria) "aac" "abc"
LT
```